# How can you find any macros or VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Recently taking over a new position at a company, I received the [attached document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6h1gcc5ztjkv9qj/Status%20Report.xlsm?dl=0) today. It seems like there is either VBA or Macros attached that changes the format whenever I go to print. Is there a way to find those? The only thing that I could find were 2 modules that were meant to protect and unprotect the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Basic Editor's *Project Explorer* only displays modules, which makes it annoyingly tedious to know what's coded where, especially in a larger project, or in a workbook with many worksheets - code can be lurking literally anywhere!

I manage the [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) open-source project - we build a VBIDE add-in that enhances the VBE's navigational tooling (and several other things) - for example the *Code Explorer* allows you to drill down to procedure level, and any module that contains code will have a little "expand" arrow:

[image: Rubberduck's Code Explorer drilling down to member level]

Makes it much easier to see what modules contain code, at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a workbook macro triggered by the BeforePrint event. Check the ThisWorkbook tab in the same place you found the Modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want (or you are not allowed to) to install any third party software ([MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com/) or [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) would ease your job however), you may consider adding the following code in an additional module and adding this library - "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library":

```
Option Explicit

Private strSubsInfo As String

Public Sub GetFunctionAndSubNames()

    Dim item            As Variant

    strSubsInfo = ""

    For Each item In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If ComponentTypeToString(vbext_ct_StdModule) = "Code Module" Then
            ListProcedures item.Name, False
            'Debug.Print item.CodeModule.lines(1, item.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
        End If
    Next item

    Debug.Print strSubsInfo

End Sub

Private Sub ListProcedures(strName As String, Optional blnWithParentInfo = False)

    'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library

    Dim VBProj          As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp          As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod         As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum         As Long
    Dim ProcName        As String
    Dim ProcKind        As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(strName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1

        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)

            If blnWithParentInfo Then
                strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & strName & "." & ProcName
            Else
                strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & ProcName
            End If

            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
        Loop

    End With

End Sub

Function ComponentTypeToString(ComponentType As VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType) As String

    Select Case ComponentType

        Case vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
            ComponentTypeToString = "ActiveX Designer"

        Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
            ComponentTypeToString = "Class Module"

        Case vbext_ct_Document
            ComponentTypeToString = "Document Module"

        Case vbext_ct_MSForm
            ComponentTypeToString = "UserForm"

        Case vbext_ct_StdModule
            ComponentTypeToString = "Code Module"

        Case Else
            ComponentTypeToString = "Unknown Type: " & CStr(ComponentType)

    End Select

End Function
```

As a result you would all the functions and subs printed in the immediate window.

[GitHub with credits to CPearson](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/VBE/PrintAllProcedures.vb).